# Почему после добавления новых инпутов, значения в старых пропадают

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему после добавления новых инпутов, значения в старых пропадают. И как это можно будет исправить? Заранее спасибо :)

```js
function addStr() {
  let str = document.getElementById('list');
  str.innerHTML +=
    `<div class="fillingField">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="number">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <input type="text">
            </div>`;
}
document.getElementById("addStr").onclick = addStr;
```

```html
<fieldset class="list" id="list">
  <div class="fillingField">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="number">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<button type="button" id="addStr">Добавить строку для заполнения</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function addStr() {
  let str = document.getElementById('list');
  const node = document.createElement('div');
  node.classList.add('fillingField');
  node.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text">
  `;
  str.appendChild(node);
}
document.getElementById("addStr").onclick = addStr;
```

```html
<fieldset class="list" id="list">
  <div class="fillingField">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="number">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<button type="button" id="addStr">Добавить строку для заполнения</button>
```